Fitting a wave function to time-series data
I have velocity data sampled over time and I'd like to find some equation/function that can be used to describe it. My data looks like this figure

As you can see from the image the data is not a simple sin or cos wave and I'm struggling to find a way to find/fit some equation to the data. My signal processing knowledge is quite limited.
Here's the down-sampled data as an example:
xdata = np.array([11.79, 11.87, 11.95, 12.03, 12.11, 12.19, 12.27, 12.35, 12.43,
       12.51, 12.59, 12.67, 12.75, 12.83, 12.91, 12.99, 13.07, 13.15,
       13.23, 13.31, 13.39, 13.47, 13.55, 13.63, 13.71, 13.79, 13.87,
       13.95, 14.03, 14.11, 14.19, 14.27, 14.35, 14.43, 14.51, 14.59,
       14.67, 14.75, 14.83, 14.91, 14.99, 15.07, 15.15, 15.23, 15.31,
       15.39, 15.47, 15.55, 15.63, 15.71, 15.79, 15.87, 15.95, 16.03,
       16.11, 16.19, 16.27, 16.35, 16.43, 16.51, 16.59, 16.67, 16.75,
       16.83, 16.91, 16.99, 17.07, 17.15, 17.23, 17.31, 17.39, 17.47,
       17.55, 17.63, 17.71, 17.79, 17.87, 17.95, 18.03, 18.11, 18.19,
       18.27, 18.35, 18.43, 18.51, 18.59, 18.67, 18.75, 18.83, 18.91,
       18.99, 19.07, 19.15, 19.23, 19.31, 19.39, 19.47, 19.55, 19.63,
       19.71, 19.79, 19.87, 19.95])

ydata = np.array([ 1.86470801e-05, -3.05185889e-03, -4.53502752e-03, -5.01501449e-03,
       -7.61753339e-03, -7.89916120e-03, -8.45710261e-03, -7.64640792e-03,
       -7.28613761e-03, -6.07402134e-03, -4.21708665e-03, -2.53126644e-03,
       -1.38970318e-03,  1.59394526e-05,  1.91879565e-03,  3.10854836e-03,
        3.37327421e-03,  4.56715556e-03,  5.59283055e-03,  7.38842610e-03,
        7.62706763e-03,  9.14228858e-03,  1.24410442e-02,  1.47384372e-02,
        1.50136837e-02,  1.14957746e-02,  9.03580024e-03,  7.04710182e-03,
        6.94429062e-03,  6.57961389e-03,  5.25393124e-03,  4.75389627e-03,
        2.49195903e-03,  2.41027520e-03,  1.67260849e-03,  5.02479585e-04,
        2.35275116e-04, -1.91204237e-03, -1.38367516e-03, -1.02639516e-03,
        2.78570931e-04, -4.42114657e-04,  2.86560704e-04,  5.69435589e-04,
       -2.94260316e-04,  6.68917718e-05, -1.61045579e-03, -2.32730345e-03,
       -2.55154534e-03, -4.01547893e-03, -4.72977248e-03, -5.12847064e-03,
       -7.10974182e-03, -6.99822300e-03, -8.07665704e-03, -8.84851229e-03,
       -9.09903075e-03, -1.03180810e-02, -1.14544281e-02, -1.21251714e-02,
       -1.30148026e-02, -1.29700705e-02, -1.25293732e-02, -1.12340153e-02,
       -1.05980279e-02, -8.51107110e-03, -6.05923880e-03, -4.50314785e-03,
       -3.11505449e-03, -1.61344075e-03, -1.90893378e-04,  8.53961182e-04,
        2.53364048e-03,  3.00061370e-03,  4.13971717e-03,  5.83572401e-03,
        7.97330030e-03,  9.11719022e-03,  1.07586221e-02,  1.20721136e-02,
        1.24900520e-02,  1.07001078e-02,  9.77437191e-03,  8.30650537e-03,
        6.17321981e-03,  4.27379777e-03,  3.53587465e-03,  2.37557043e-03,
        1.66114222e-03,  6.83006538e-04, -6.38602576e-04, -1.54135169e-03,
       -9.86915409e-04, -1.58287464e-03, -2.02820728e-03, -1.53065658e-03,
       -8.52157455e-04,  1.62949595e-03,  8.56897304e-04,  1.20745000e-03,
       -1.06239388e-03, -2.39230381e-03, -2.39669751e-03])

My other data is quite regular and I can usually fit with a sin or cos function using scipy.optimize like in the following example.

def cos_func(x, D, E):
    y = D*np.cos(E*x)
    return y

guess = [0.01, 4]
parameters, covariance = curve_fit(cos_func, xdata, ydata, p0=guess)
print(parameters)

fit_D = parameters[0]
fit_E = parameters[1]

fit_cosine = cos_func(xdata, fit_D, fit_E)

plt.plot(xdata, ydata, 'o', label='data')
plt.plot(xdata, fit_cosine, '-', label='fit')


But that fails miserably on this data:

What function or type of wave should I be fitting the data with here? I presume it needs to be some sin/cos compound wave with differing amplitudes to create a wave like this but I don't know how to automatically find the correct type of equation before optimising the parameters with scipy.

Might be a good idea to FFT it first, to pick up the dominant frequency. Then low-pass filter it to remove the noise.

edit the title and remove "complex", this might be misleading

Do you by chance have more data available than you show here? Any method of fitting a non-trivial waveform will benefit substantially from having a lot more wavelengths to work with. lastchance's suggestion to use FFT is a good one, but it won't tell you much you don't already know unless you have a lot more data.

The waveform is clearly a triangle wave with some additional crossover distortion and (at least) one higher frequency component for the same shape on the falling edge. There is insufficient length of data to be sure about anything more. The sine wave fit shown is rather bad. OP might want to look at how astronomers do this sort of thing for variable stars, essentially folding the data back on itself at the period of the oscillation and averaging to drive down the systematic noise.

@BrendanMitchell There is more data - it's a well behaved repeating pattern and I've only shown a portion of the data and cycles.

@MartinBrown is there a good example of what astronomers do? Astropy?

I can't recommend any particular one but there are several aimed at everything from amateur hobbyists to exoplanet researchers. This one astrobase looks plausible and accessible. The answer below also looks reasonable to me but I am uncomfortable not seeing at least 8-10 cycles of the waveform before passing judgement on the quality of fit. What is it? A chemical clock of some sort??

@MartinBrown Will look into. It's a velocity wave in a liquid from a stirring process - so quite consistent

@lastchance Running a FFT helps to better pick out the frequency but there is still some phase shift or angle missing from the fit. https://imgur.com/yLUZ9Ic

Yes, but once you have the main frequency you have a chance of getting a suitable curve fit; most routines do considerably better if they have a good initial guess. Clearly your data isn’t a sinusoid, but there are plenty of other periodic shapes. I managed to fit the sum of two sawtooths reasonably well to your data. You could do with providing more cycles.

what is the underlying process and what "models" for this waveform make sense? we hate to guess. details required.

@ChristophRackwitz The data shows the velocity at the surface of a fluid resulting from a continuous stirring process. Any (preferably simple) equation that can describe this time-based variation is ok as long as it captures most of the feature - does not need to be perfect for this case

Can you provide more cycles of data, please, @jpmorr. There is sufficient difference between the two cycles here to make it difficult to choose the most appropriate model. To be honest I'd still go with FFT-ing any periodic signal. Just keep a combination of the dominant few frequencies (NOT just a single sinusoid) as it would then extend naturally your simpler data. There is theory for steep water waves (Airy waves -> cnoidal waves), but your waves simply look as if they are breaking.

@lastchance I will try to access tomorrow, I only have the limited sample right now

Really though. Listen to lastchance's comments and perform simple FFT reduction. Shown here with a few different reduction lengths:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

xdelta = 0.08
xdata = np.arange(11.79, 20, xdelta)
ydata = np.array((
    1.86470801e-05, -3.05185889e-03, -4.53502752e-03, -5.01501449e-03,
    -7.61753339e-03, -7.89916120e-03, -8.45710261e-03, -7.64640792e-03,
    -7.28613761e-03, -6.07402134e-03, -4.21708665e-03, -2.53126644e-03,
    -1.38970318e-03,  1.59394526e-05,  1.91879565e-03,  3.10854836e-03,
    3.37327421e-03,  4.56715556e-03,  5.59283055e-03,  7.38842610e-03,
    7.62706763e-03,  9.14228858e-03,  1.24410442e-02,  1.47384372e-02,
    1.50136837e-02,  1.14957746e-02,  9.03580024e-03,  7.04710182e-03,
    6.94429062e-03,  6.57961389e-03,  5.25393124e-03,  4.75389627e-03,
    2.49195903e-03,  2.41027520e-03,  1.67260849e-03,  5.02479585e-04,
    2.35275116e-04, -1.91204237e-03, -1.38367516e-03, -1.02639516e-03,
    2.78570931e-04, -4.42114657e-04,  2.86560704e-04,  5.69435589e-04,
    -2.94260316e-04,  6.68917718e-05, -1.61045579e-03, -2.32730345e-03,
    -2.55154534e-03, -4.01547893e-03, -4.72977248e-03, -5.12847064e-03,
    -7.10974182e-03, -6.99822300e-03, -8.07665704e-03, -8.84851229e-03,
    -9.09903075e-03, -1.03180810e-02, -1.14544281e-02, -1.21251714e-02,
    -1.30148026e-02, -1.29700705e-02, -1.25293732e-02, -1.12340153e-02,
    -1.05980279e-02, -8.51107110e-03, -6.05923880e-03, -4.50314785e-03,
    -3.11505449e-03, -1.61344075e-03, -1.90893378e-04,  8.53961182e-04,
    2.53364048e-03,  3.00061370e-03,  4.13971717e-03,  5.83572401e-03,
    7.97330030e-03,  9.11719022e-03,  1.07586221e-02,  1.20721136e-02,
    1.24900520e-02,  1.07001078e-02,  9.77437191e-03,  8.30650537e-03,
    6.17321981e-03,  4.27379777e-03,  3.53587465e-03,  2.37557043e-03,
    1.66114222e-03,  6.83006538e-04, -6.38602576e-04, -1.54135169e-03,
    -9.86915409e-04, -1.58287464e-03, -2.02820728e-03, -1.53065658e-03,
    -8.52157455e-04,  1.62949595e-03,  8.56897304e-04,  1.20745000e-03,
    -1.06239388e-03, -2.39230381e-03, -2.39669751e-03,
))

freq = np.fft.rfftfreq(n=xdata.size, d=xdelta)
fft = np.fft.rfft(a=ydata)
plt.plot(freq, np.abs(fft))

plt.figure()
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, label='full')
for length in range(14, 4, -3):
    fft[length:] = 0
    inverted = np.fft.irfft(fft)
    plt.plot(xdata[:-1], inverted, label=length)
plt.legend()
plt.show()

Spectrum

Reduced time series

Equation
With outer() and @ both representing a matrix multiplication, the expression for the inverse real FFT is
cut = 5
n = xdata.size

inverse = 2/n * (
    np.exp(
        2j*np.pi/n * np.outer(
            np.arange(n),
            np.arange(cut),
        )
    ) @ fft[:cut]
).real


OK, that fits great but what is the equation of the fitted curve - the equation is the most important part for me.

It's the sum of sines+cosines that fundamentally defines the Fourier series: inverse transform shown in Wikipedia in Euler form: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Definition

@jpmorr Added the inverse equation. Stack Overflow does not support MathJax so I show it as a direct numpy expression.

I highly recommend you don't use curve_fit for periodic signals. For instance, check this post and there are many other examples with the same answer: curve_fit cannot accurately estimate frequency, which means over time the fitted and actual stray from each other.
Instead, this seems like a very nice dataset to apply Gaussian Regression. Here's an example:
# Do Gaussian Regression
kernel = 1 * RBF(length_scale=1.0, length_scale_bounds=(1e-2, 1e2)) # define the kernel
GP = GaussianProcessRegressor(kernel=kernel, n_restarts_optimizer=9) # define the GP model
x_train = x[::5] # get training x as every 5th point
y_train = y[::5] # get training y as every 5th point
GP.fit(x_train, y_train) # fit the GP
muPredictions, sigmaPredictions = GP.predict(x, return_std=True) # predict
# plotting
plt.scatter(x, y, label = "Original") # scatter original data
plt.plot(x, muPredictions, label="Mean predictions", color = "r") # plot the mean of predictions
plt.fill_between( # fill between confidance interval
    x.ravel(),
    muPredictions - 1.96*sigmaPredictions,
    muPredictions + 1.96*sigmaPredictions,
    alpha=0.5,
    label=r"95% confidence interval",
)
plt.legend() # add legend
plt.grid() # and grid

The results will look like this:

You can make this finer or coarser the sparser you select points for training, currently it's every 5th element.
Here are the imports:
import numpy as np
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.gaussian_process import GaussianProcessRegressor
from sklearn.gaussian_process.kernels import RBF

It seems StackOverflow really likes animations, so here is one that shows the effect of sampling:

And in my opinion the optimal at 3:


This seems like a really nice solution but I can't actually get the code to work. Apart from having to reshape arrays everywhere, setting the training data to be a subset creates a problem for the predictor ValueError: X has 804 features, but GaussianProcessRegressor is expecting 161 features as input. - so I don't understand how to train of a portion of the data?

can you post a link to the full data somewhere? I can take a look later. If I remember, I had to reshape x using x.reshape(-1,1). y stays as is

basically the functions expects a column of values and currently your data is storer as a row. Therefore, do xdata.reshape(-1,1) from the get go.

Is there anyway to get the equation for the fitted curve? That's what I need to include in a model to represent this

i'm no longer near my laptop, but here is how Gaussian Regression generally looks like:  P(y|f,X)~N(y|Hβ+f,σ^2.I)

This makes a really nice looking curve fit, but I'd hazard a guess that it's not quite what OP is looking for. I get the impression that they want to find a function that describes the waveform generally, not just the data on the screen. In other words, this model interpolates well, but I think they want a model that can extrapolate, which this one will not do. For that, they want a Fourier series.

I agree @BrendanMitchell, FFT is the way to go
